# Curl command to see messages being sent from test program to webserver on linux

Tags: javascript, linux, curl, web

I just installed curl on a Linux machine.
I have a webserver and web page. 
I also have a test program that will send rti messages to the web server.

I want to be able to use curl to look at messages that are being received by the web server and were by the  test program.
I am using localHost:8080

I am new to curl but have heard that I should be able to see the messages.
What command syntax should I use with curl

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you mean is tcpdump or wireshark if you wish to inspect the traffic to your webserver